# Save existing Docx as XML using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

i have an existing word document (office 2010) and want to programatically saveAs it as XML. i was tried

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Documents.Open(@"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");
```

but its not correct.

how can i do this?

Comment: use file object to save it as xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myfile= @"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx"; 
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(myfile); 
fileInfo.MoveTo(Path.ChangeExtension(myfile, ".xml"));
```